# AngularJS - Loading named views within child states ( not abstract )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angular-ui-router, named

Alright so I am having an issue with my named views loading content into my state.

Its mostly problematic because I really do not know why it isnt working; with angular that usually means a typo but I have recreated my problem in a plunker and am getting the same results so maybe I am missing something.

**I know this question has been asked before::** however in all the results I saw on here people were putting content into an abstract state's children. what I want to do is have a state; populate it with named views as well as other content relevant to that state; then have that states children load content into the main states named views. should be simple enough and rather straight forward but alas mine will not work for me.

**Here is the link to the plunker made::**  http://plnkr.co/edit/TWCQuoIyJRvTb42Z7xxe?p=preview

as you will see the main 'papers' state is loading. however none of the content from the named views is being loaded into the 'papers' state from its child state 'papers.views'.

Code for reference:

**Module declaration and state config(app.js)**

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', [ 'ui.router' ] );

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/papers');
      // States
      $stateProvider
      .state( 'papers',  {
          url: "/papers",
          templateUrl: 'papers.html'
      }) // nested paper state + views
      .state( 'papers.views', {
          views: {
            '@papers': {
              templateUrl: 'papers.home.html'
            },
            'paper1@papers': {
              templateUrl: 'papers.paper1.html'
            },
            'paper2@papers': {
              templateUrl: 'papers.paper2.html'
            }
          }
      })
    }
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

**Index page (papers.html loading here):**

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

**papers page ( where nested views are supposed to be loading )**

```
<h1>This is the papers page. other views should load in here</h1>

<div ui-view ></div>
<div ui-view="paper1" ></div>
<div ui-view="paper2" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, how to fix this is to add two lines:

- change your parent to be `abstract : true` and
- force child to define `url : ''`

There is [**an upated and working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ze1pZWHkzlgyUBic6HiL?p=preview), this is the updated state def:

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/papers');
  // States
  $stateProvider
  .state( 'papers',  {
      // NEW LINE
      abstract: true,
      url: "/papers",
      templateUrl: 'papers.html'
  }) // nested paper state + views
  .state( 'papers.views', {
      // NEW LINE - because parent is abstract, same url here - this will be loaded
      url: '',
      views: {
        '@papers': {
          templateUrl: 'papers.home.html'
        },
        'paper1@papers': {
          templateUrl: 'papers.paper1.html'
        },
        'paper2@papers': {
          templateUrl: 'papers.paper2.html'
        }
      }
  })
```

More details about this in documentation:

**[How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)**

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ze1pZWHkzlgyUBic6HiL?p=preview)

Another way could be to change the default:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/papers/view');
```

And add url: '/view' to child state:

```
  ...
  .state( 'papers.views', {
      url: '/view',
      views: {
      ...
```

Check this [version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YNqg48jbnagTdmg05BTu?p=preview)

Comment: hm, well this is a sub section of my main app so chaning the $urlRouteProvider wont do. but the first answer Ill give a try. I thought it would be possible to load child states into a non-abstract parent as long as there was a named view but I suppose that just is not how angular-ui-router works, thanks for the feedback! Ill give it a go and mark you as the answer once I find it working

Comment: Checked it out; its perfect. I was not aware one could load a template into an abstract. so this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, awesome tool